# Why do my buttons stay highlighted simultaneously?

Tags: windows, winapi, visual-c++, button, window

You usually only have *one* button that looks like a "default button".

However, I made a child window and placed two buttons in it (with the child window as their parent). Then I put the child window inside a dialog and displayed it.

Suddenly, the buttons *stay* highlighted even when I click other buttons!

Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your child window needs the `WS_EX_CONTROLPARENT` style, to allow the dialog to handle the notifications from its children.